# CASE inside GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can I selectively choose the columns for group by? Can I use CASE inside it. It compiles alright but doesnt seem to work at run time.

example:

```
GROUP BY o.organization_name ol.org_level_name, work_date,
 CASE WHEN @org_level_type = 'Department' THEN jd.job_code ELSE jd.job_department_id END
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edited Answer

This is probably not a good idea. Just divide it into 2 separate queries to avoid unnecessary sort operations from a one size fits all query.

You could put the bulk of the query that is doing the joins on tables `o`,`jd`,`ol` (without a `GROUP BY`) into a View to avoid having to repeat this.

#### Original Answer

(Assuming the 2 columns are of compatible datatypes)

```
select o.organization_name,
       ol.org_level_name,
       work_date,
       code_or_dept
FROM   ...
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE
                             WHEN @org_level_type = 'Department' THEN
                             jd.job_code
                             ELSE jd.job_department_id
                           END AS code_or_dept) c
GROUP  BY o.organization_name,
          ol.org_level_name,
          work_date,
          code_or_dept
```

Comment: oh god, what a superb approach! Worked like a charm. Please could someone explain what CROSS APPY does? Excellent answer.

Comment: @user503510 - The `CROSS APPLY` just allows you to define the column alias once and use it both in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` without repeating the whole `case` expression. But thinking about it I think the query plans from trying to do this conditional `group by`may well have unnecessary sort operations in them compared to just doing them as separate queries.

Comment: Thanks Martin. While we are at it, what happens if I do this:      CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE
                             WHEN @org_level_type = 'Department' THEN
                             jd.job_code
                             ELSE NULL
                           END AS code_or_dept) c

Comment: What I want to know by doing this is what if I may want to include or completely omit (without any replacement column) certain column from group by. thanks.

Comment: Well in that instance all of the rows would be regarded as being in the same group so you wouldn't get the additional groups for each `job_code`

Comment: To check it I did put NULL in group by list but I got this error: "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: @user503510 - Yes. You can't group by the literal `null` but it is valid syntax in the `case` as that does reference `jd.job_code` still.